# Get the title from a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a jQuery tooltip.

In a nutshell, the jQuery creates the popup from another HTML page.

**EDIT**
   i put up an example. [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/76hSB/)

So I need to grab the title from the popup. When I use the `document.title` or whatever, it echos the title from the current page and not the popup.

```
<div id='JT_close_right'>"+title+"</div>
```

I need the title in a variable:

```
var title = (pop-up page's title)
```

Comment: You are not providing enough information. Do you want to get the page title of the HTML page, the popup is created from?

Comment: After reading your below comment, i agree with felix, need a bit more info. If that's what you're trying to do, i think your better off adding the title value in the title attribute of the area tag, and use that.

Comment: yes. theres a lot of code so i didnt include it all...

Comment: ive got the page with the img map. On area.hover a pop up shows and the content is taken from the href of the area. all of the standard markup is on the pages that are populating the content (body tag,html, head, title).

Comment: I'm not certain this will work, but try querying for a title tag underneath the containing div of the popup, which i believe was id="JT" `var title = $('#JT title').first().html();`

Answer (score 0):

simply use:

```
var title = $('#JT_close_right').html();
```

Since you are populating that element with the title in the function, you just need to grab that element by its id. The popup you are creating is not a separate window, but just using a div as an overlay overtop of the current content, so it does not have its own document.title for example, or document object for that matter.

Comment: its an image map.. heres some code `<area class="jTip" onclick="return false"  id="panel2" name="VIP" shape="circle" coords="462,545,29" href="/map/resources/panel2.html?width=400" />` so its supposed to grab the title of the pop up

Comment: im not populating that ID though the var title is. so its a little more dynamic.